# PHP SESSIONS are empty after reload page

Tags: php, session, server

I have code

```
<?php
require_once("lib/functions.php");
$page = new page;



if(isset($_POST['jmeno'])){
    $page->mailit($_POST, $_SESSION['result']);
}

$_SESSION['f'] = rand(1,9);
$_SESSION['s'] = rand(1,9);
$_SESSION['result'] = $_SESSION['f'] + $_SESSION['s'];

?>
```

Before `POST` form it prints the right values, but after `POST` form the sessions are empty. I don't know why, looks like something is bad configured. So it's always show Bad counted result

Here is session configuration....
[image]

Comment: have you used start_session(); ?

Comment: Yes, it is in functions.php

Comment: when I print_r $_SESSION before post form it's show me good values, but If I post form $_SESSIONS are emepty

Comment: Can you show us what a print_r of $_SESSION shows?

Comment: Array ( [f] => 9 [s] => 6 [result] => 15 )

Comment: But when I print it after post 'jmeno' shows Array()

Comment: Are you using named sessions?

Answer (score 4):

make sure that this line of code:

```
session_start();
```

Is at the beggining of your php file, right after the opening php tag `<?php`

This line of code is used to start new or resume existing session, please see php manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I starting it, if i not start it it's show me no sessions values, its looks like that sessions are reseting after post form

Comment: @koca79331 do you have this `session_start();` at the beggining of every php page you're using?

Comment: @koca79331 sorry, the line should be `session_start();`. thanks to @Ahmad for the edit

Comment: Yes it is on the start of every page becouse it is in functions.php

Comment: @koca79331 you are using a different file to post right? with function.php included? if  `$session_start()` is not the issue, you might be using `unset()` somewhere, incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file had UTF-8 encoding. (not UTF-8-BOM)